# Is there any way to skip generic function types without explicitly defining them?

Tags: typescript

We are trying to build a generic function type for API requests. This type should accept a bunch of optional generic types: payload, response, query parameters, path parameters and config types.

```
export type ApiServiceBaseMethod<
  P = never,
  R = void,
  Q extends QueryParams | undefined = Record<string, string | number>,
  M extends PathParams | undefined = Record<string, string | number>,
  C extends ApiServiceMethodConfig = Record<string, string>,
> = ({
  payload,
  pathParams,
  queryParams,
  config,
}: {
  payload?: P;
  pathParams?: M;
  queryParams?: Q;
  config?: C;
}) => Promise<AxiosResponse<R>>;
```

One of the many possible examples of problems related to the clean and understandable code principles is if we try to use this this type when defining only e.g. generic `M` type, meaning we have to manually set every generic type prior to generic type `M` to `unknown`/`undefined`/`never` (whatever).

Is there any way to solve this? Skipping generic types would be ideal, but TS doesn't have that ability. If not, is there any other way to approach this problem, without defining specific sub function types (variations)?

Comment: N.B. `=> Promise<AxiosResponse<R>>` is a complete fiction. It seems really odd that you would go to all the trouble of typing out the arguments to a function like this so precisely but leave such a gaping hole in the type of your return value. The only real type of data deserialized from over the wire is `unknown`, if you want to return anything else make the caller pass a type predicate function as a validator.

Comment: Why? The response can sometimes be an actual custom DTO type or the server can just return a blank 200 without any body. That's why it defaults to void

Comment: What you're asking is essentially impossible if you still want types to be inferred.  For generic types there are workarounds (because no inference happens there) but for generic functions I don't think anything is better than overloads.

Comment: @mmozedev it's problematic because there is no validation that the returned response is actually of the type that the caller passes as a type parameter. I can pass `{ foo: string }` and the response will come back as whatever, the compiler will be silent, and the code will blow up at runtime. Either return `Promise<AxiosResponse<unknown>>` to all callers so it's clear they need to validate the response or make them pass you a validator `(x: unknown) => x is R` so that you validate that your returned value is actually of type `R`. An API where it's easy to do the wrong thing is a bad API

Comment: The signature is *too* generic.  Any type param that appears only once is suspect, and one that appears only in the return type is *extremely* suspect. Callers specify type args, not implementers. A function claiming to be `<X>()=>X`  is lying, because at runtime it's just `f()` with no dependence on anything related to `X`.  Unless you can demonstrate a useful difference between this and `(a: { payload?: any; pathParams?: PathParams; queryParams?: QueryParams; config?: ApiSe⋯fig;}) => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>` then I'd say you should probably re-evaluate your approach.

Comment: Ok, but how do I then define response type @jcalz?

Comment: Also, do I then completely drop this approach trying to define a super generic Function type?

Comment: "How do I then define response type"?  I don't know, is there any relationship between the parameters and the expected response type?